# Is overloading int function with the same long long function has any point?

Tags: c++, function, memory, overloading

Here is a simple example:

```
int function (int n) { 
    //code 
}

long long function (long long n) {
    //absolutely the same code but intended to work with bigger values
}
```

I was thinking about saving extra memory (if you use it with variables of *small* types) AND making it more universal (if you use it with variables of *big* types)

I hope you get my idea here - dont use long long if you put something like 15 in there, instead use overload for smaller types (like int).

I think I'm missing something here. Should i even make this overload? Can I make *most universal* AND *most optimal* function without overloading it for *each existing **integer** type* (short, int, long, long long...)?

Comment: You can do `template<typename T> T func(T n)`, or even `template<std::integral INT> INT func(INT n)` to constrain it to integer types

Comment: `15` is an `int` so it will call the version taking an `int`. The overload resolution happens at compile time and the actual _value_ of the argument is a runtime property which is not taken into consideration.

Comment: Also *saving extra memory* — Does it really save any memories? Do you need to allocate 1 million objects of type `T` on the fly, or do you just `return n*2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're writing code for reasonably-recent personal computers or web servers, having a separate `int` version is probably a premature optimization, given that *most of these machines have 64-bit processors anyway*, so calculations with 64-bit `long long` should be fast.

OTOH, if you're writing for an 8/16/32-bit embedded system on which 64-bit arithmetic is dramatically slow, it might be a worthwhile speed optimization.

But it's still unlikely to be helpful in terms of *memory* usage due to the fact that having duplicate implementations of a function will increase the size of your compiled code, thus cancelling the benefit of using less memory for your variables.  Unless that function takes an array of possibly *millions* of integers instead of just one, in which case the data size is more of a concern than the code size.

If you do insist on having overloaded functions for different integer sizes, I recommend using Ranoiaetep's suggestion of making it a `template` function, so as to avoid duplication in the source code.